# Can "stark" be used as a synonym to "strong"?

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

Can "stark" be used as a synonym to "strong" or "of a strong will" in a sentence like "*She was a strong person*" or  "*You need to be strong to stay sane in captivity*"?

Comment: Did you use a dictionary? How does the dictionary define "stark"? According to that, is "stark" a synonym of "strong"?

Comment: @virolino I have. Synonyms are tricky. One can never be sure they fully correspond to each others meanings.

Comment: Please provide a link to a definition where the stark = strong. Do that by editing the question, please, in order to comply with the rules of ELL.

Comment: Also, please provide an explanation (editing the question) why do you think the two words are synonyms. Do they sound synonyms to you? A friend told you? You found it in a book? On the Internet?...

Comment: @virolino But mom! Why would I be explaining it to native speakers?

Comment: Sorry, JK. But it's truly not worth my time, even though many other people may google this answer in the future.

Comment: Please do not feel offended. I did not ask you to explain the words, I asked you to explain **your understanding** of the words. According to the dictionaries I found, it is quite impossible that the two words are synonyms in any way. BTW, I am not a native English speaker myself.

Comment: Please read the rules of asking question here on ELL, it will help you get better answers faster: https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you found something like the [Merriam-Webster definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stark), which has it meaning "strong, robust". You may also note there that this is listed as an *archaic* sense of the word. That is to say, you will find it in old texts, or when people are trying to be deliberately anachronistic, but it is not used in that way now.

So **no**, you can't use it in that way if you want people to understand you.